# MVC 4 jquery.validate.unobtrusive is not working relese mode in IIS7.5 WS2008 R2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an application which is created in MVC4. I have implemented field validations for each fields. Also I integrated qtip2 plugins to show the image with tooltip text. Below the code i have changed in unobtrusive js file.

Below code is working fine in local development machine. I have changed debug=true in web.config,then it has working in hosted server.

> Why it is not working in release mode?

```
function onError(error, inputElement) {  // 'this' is the form element        
    var container = $(this).find("[data-valmsg-for='" + inputElement[0].name + "']"),
    replace = $.parseJSON(container.attr("data-valmsg-replace")) !== false;
    if (container.length > 0 && container[0].className == "field-validation-valid-icon") {
        container.removeClass("field-validation-valid-icon").addClass("field-validation-error");
    }
    else {
        container.removeClass("field-validation-valid").addClass("field-validation-error");
    }
    error.data("unobtrusiveContainer", container);

    if (replace) {

        if ($(error).text() == "") {
            container.removeClass("ui-state-error-icon").removeClass("ui-icon-alert");
        }
        else {
            container.addClass("ui-state-error-icon").addClass("ui-icon-alert");

            $(container).qtip({
                overwrite: true,
                content: $(error).text(),
                style: {
                    classes: 'ui-tooltip-red'
                }
            });
        }
    }
    else {
        error.hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Reference jquery directly in your view:
   @section Scripts
   {
  <script src="../Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
 <script src="../Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src="../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
 <script src="../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}
```